# Rshiny cannot download knitr PDF "pdflatex: command not found" on CentOS8

Tags: shiny, r-markdown

We could not generate and download the PDF by Rshiny. But
`rmakrdown::render("xxx.Rmd")`
in R console worked well.

We tried this example (https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/download-knitr-reports.html). Word and HTML could be generated but not PDF.

The following is the error message:

```
[WARNING] (pagebreak.lua) requires at least Pandoc 2.1. Lua Filter skipped.
[WARNING] (latex-div.lua) requires at least Pandoc 2.1. Lua Filter skipped.
Warning in system2(..., stdout = if (use_file_stdout()) f1 else FALSE, stderr = f2) :
error in running command
! sh: pdflatex: command not found

Warning: Error in : LaTeX failed to compile report.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See report.log for more info.
1: runApp
```

Our systmem is

```
> sessionInfo()
> R version 4.2.1 (2022-06-23)
> Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)
> Running under: Alibaba Cloud Linux 3 (Soaring Falcon)
> 
> Matrix products: default
> BLAS/LAPACK: /usr/lib64/libopenblaso-r0.3.12.so
> 
> locale:
>  [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
>  [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
>  [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
>  [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
>  [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
> [11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       
> 
> attached base packages:
> [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
> 
> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
> [1] compiler_4.2.1
```

The path seems to be wrong, but how should we set the path of pdflatex?

We have updated TexLive into the latest version, as well as R packages rmarkdown and tinytex.